# Tomcat server access restriction cause that Websocket doesn't connect

Tags: tomcat, websocket

When I config the tomcat server with user control access, the chat client based on Websocket can't connect to the server, but the rest of components of the page run correctly. Do you know how to make websocket work with this configuration?
I've configured the control access changing the tomcat-users.xml file ( adding into the "tomcat-users" username, password and rol) and changing the web.xml file adding:

```
 <security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>user</role-name>
 </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

and

```
 <login-config>
 <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 <realm-name> Access Control </realm-name>
 </login-config>
```

The page including chat websocket run perfectly without control access, but by the moment i need to implement this restriction on the server.

Comment: what version of tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

After long time looking for an answer in internet, I have found many comments indicating that the implementation of HTTP Authentication Method is not compatible with Websocket. Authentication must be done with other methods.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855812/how-to-secure-access-to-a-websocket-servlet-class-on-tomcat-with-http-authentica)

[link2](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/129j6cmshc/websocketservlet-basic-auth)